# Play 2.X ScalaRouting Boolean Parameter

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

How can I use boolean in route definition?

If I use this way,

```
GET     /user/:userName   controllers.AppController.user(userName, registerDone:Boolean?=0)
```

it throws this error:

> ```
> [error]  found   : Int(0)
> [error]  required: Boolean
> ```

If I use this way,

```
GET     /user/:userName   controllers.AppController.user(userName, registerDone:Boolean?=false)
```

it throws this error:

> bad request at: /user/aajjblack?registerDone=true, Cannot parse
>   parameter registerDone as Boolean: should be 0 or 1

Controller:

```
public static Result user(final String userName, Boolean registerDone) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use... `Int` instead

```
GET  /user/:userName  controllers.AppController.user(userName, registerDone: Int?=0)
```

action:

```
public static Result user(final String userName, int registerDone) {
    if(registerDone == 0){
        return badRequest();
    }

    // do something with registered user...
    return ok();
}
```

It's simplest replace of any kind  of booleans, as you can just check if `registerDone` is bigger than 0 (and it still keeps type-safety).